Installing Wine without Internet on CENTOS 7.6
I would like to install wine without internet access. I sideloaded the wine.sh file, along with the configuration. I have make installed in the system. I have been looking online for a way to clear up an error message that says I don't have the tools to install 32-bit development libraries. Where can I find a resource to install such tools, and what are the tools it is missing exactly? I would like to keep in mind my system does not have internet access, and I would like to use a thumb drive to mount them in and possibly use yum localinstall *.rpm to install the files.

WINE typically asks for 32-bit support because many Windows software still is 32-bit. You'd need to install the full architecture so connecting it to the internet is really the best option. You may want to use a temporary USB tethering from your phone if no other option.
